# Play Services Hint Request cannot display phone numbers in Android 12

Tags: android, phone-number, hint

When I trying to retrieve phone number with Credentials api some device failed to showing phone number picker dialog and just showing empty dialog and the dialog disappear quickly with sliding animation.

**Below is my code sample.**

```
val hintRequest = HintRequest.Builder().setPhoneNumberIdentifierSupported(true).build()
        val options = CredentialsOptions.Builder().forceEnableSaveDialog().build()
        val credentialsClient = Credentials.getClient(applicationContext, options)
        val intent = credentialsClient.getHintPickerIntent(hintRequest)
        try {
            startIntentSenderForResult(
                intent.intentSender,
                CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST, null, 0, 0, 0, Bundle()
            )
        } catch (e: IntentSender.SendIntentException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }

override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
    when (requestCode) {
        CREDENTIAL_PICKER_REQUEST ->
            if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK && data != null) {
                val credential = data.getParcelableExtra<Credential>(Credential.EXTRA_KEY)
                val phoneNumber = credential?.id
            }
    }
}
```

**Dependencies:**

```
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth:20.1.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-auth-api-phone:18.0.1'
implementation 'androidx.work:work-runtime-ktx:2.7.1'
```

It's working fine in below Android 12 but not able to work in Android 12
Is There any solution for the same?

Answer (score 2):

This is a know bug to google, when the SIM does not provide the phone number:

You can star this issue:
https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77884951

The initial filing however was on Apr 11, 2018 and there is no update yet. So I would consider living either with the UI glitch or disable that functionality.

There has been an update on the auth library:
https://developers.google.com/android/guides/releases#february_01_2022

But I was not able to find any changelog.
Lets just hope, Google will fix this issue in future.

**EDIT:**
After re-reading your question, this issue does not answer your question. Might be a permission problem, have you tried downgrading your auth version for a retest?